# push to github without sending changes that are already in another fork

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repository on github and didn't pull from parent for some time.

Since then, a lot of changes accumulated in parent (including many large files).
I've pulled them into my local repo relatively quickly and did some commits on top of that.

Now I try to push it back to my github repo but with my low upload speed it will take forever since my origin repo lacks all the changes that I just pulled from the parent.

Is there a way to directly transmit objects from one github repo to another, some sort of remote git fetch ?

Comment: So you want to fetch from the original project to your github fork withoug going through a local repository, right?

Comment: Yes, preferably without recreating project as suggested below.

Comment: You can try some online IDEs with git support, like [Cloud9](https://c9.io/), [Codenvy](https://codenvy.com/) or [Nitrous.IO](https://www.nitrous.io/). I remember watching demo in which full featured shell was launched right in the browser in which presenter executed just a regular *nix commands (he even launched Vim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone over the Github [help](https://help.github.com) and [API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) to see if they mention any way of doing that but found nothing. Their guides for syncing always explicitly include pull and push via a local repository.

What is important to understand is that what you are asking for is not part of Git. Git does not offer a way of issuing remote Git commands. This means that Github would need to implement this functionality themselves.

A different approach might be a service (I don't know of any such service though) that offers "external buffering" for Git repositories. The idea being that you tell that host what to do with the repositories and when it's done, it will delete it's local clone of the repository.

There is one API call that [*nearly* does what you want](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/): it merges two branches on Github without going through a local repository. However, it can only handle branches from the same repository.

My advice: [open an issue](https://github.com/contact) with Github and ask them to implement direct syncing. I think, since there's already the *merge* API call, the cost might not be too high.

Comment: I've requested this feature from GitHub and they are thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of your modifications locally AND there's nothing in your fork's pull requests, issues, wikis, etc. that you need to preserve, you could.

1. Delete your fork on GitHub (or leave it, or rename it)
2. Fork the upstream repo on GitHub again.
3. Add/change your remote to point to the new repo (if you changed the url).

   ```
   git remote set-url <new github url>
   ```
4. Fetch and push.

The fetch should find no changes and the push should only send your new snapshots.